# How to have Billiards like physics in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm new to SpriteKit and am trying to make a Billiards game but it just doesn't seem to be working properly.  The balls don't bounce off each other or the pool cue.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is some sample code of one of the balls and the pool cue.  Any help will be appreciated!

```
class PoolTableScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  struct PhysicsCatagory {
    static let None : UInt32 = 0 //0
    static let PokeBall : UInt32 = 0b1 //1
    static let PoolCue : UInt32 = 0b1000 //5
    static let All : UInt32 = UInt32.max
  }

  let ballPoke = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"pokeBall")
  let cuePool = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "poolCue")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody 


    ballPoke.name = "ballPoke"
    ballPoke.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    ballPoke.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5)
    ballPoke.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width*0.25, y:self.frame.size.height/2)
    ballPoke.zPosition = 100
    ballPoke.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
    ballPoke.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true 
    ballPoke.physicsBody?.restitution = 10 
    ballPoke.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0 
    self.addChild(ballPoke)

  cuePool.name = "poolCue"
    cuePool.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 500)
    cuePool.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    cuePool.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width*0.20, y: self.frame.size.height/4)
    cuePool.zPosition = 100
    cuePool.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    cuePool.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    cuePool.physicsBody?.restitution = 10
    cuePool.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    self.addChild(cuePool)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      let positionOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

      ballPoke.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.PokeBall
      ballPoke.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.BlueBall | PhysicsCatagory.OrangeBall | PhysicsCatagory.Border | PhysicsCatagory.PoolCue

 cuePool.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.PoolCue
      cuePool.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.BlueBall | PhysicsCatagory.OrangeBall | PhysicsCatagory.PokeBall

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the 'category' property of the various physics bodies, else nothing will collide. You might also have to set the 'collisionBitMask' property (the default is for everything to collide with everything) and possible the 'contactTestBitMask' if you want to implement a  'didBeginContact' function. (default is for nothing to notify your program when a contact occurs).

Comment: @Steve Ives I set the collisionBitMask.  The spriteNodes collide but they don't bounce off each other like normal pool balls would. They just move slightly.  Is there a way to make they bounce off each other with more velocity?

Comment: You did - sorry, missed that. Try setting 'restitution' to 1.0 and 'linearDamping\' to 0.0 for all physics bodies. I got some pretty bouncy sprites with those settings.

Comment: You can use restitution values higher than 1.0, too. Not particularly helpful when much higher, but values like 1.05 and 1.1 can be useful, sometimes, to accentuate events. Not real, but game-like ;)

Comment: Hello Developers, need your help and support. I am new in SpriteKit, right now I am learning SpriteKit from 0, I need demo app for billiards (pool table) game. I need for learning purpose. acutely I am confused where am i going to start ? It would be nice if you give me billiards demo app source code in swift. Thank you.